# What is the best alternative for the following situation?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm using a JSONB field in my Postgresql database to store the following document. I own thousands of documents. I need to create reports with this data, but the search is very slow.

If I need to create a report stating the new users of a month, I need to go through the entire document comparing if the user is in one month and not in another.

**Message document:**

```
[{"recipient":1,"user":4,"created_at":"2016-11-10","content":"Duis aliquam convallis nunc.","is_sender_user":true},
{"recipient":1,"user":18,"created_at":"2016-12-10","content":"Proin eu mi.","is_sender_user":false},
{"recipient":1,"user":4,"created_at":"2016-11-20","content":"In hac habitasse platea dictumstm.","is_sender_user":true},
{"recipient":1,"user":20,"created_at":"2016-12-14","content":"Donec ut dolor.","is_sender_user":true},
{"recipient":1,"user":13,"created_at":"2016-12-06","content":"Nulla mollis molestie lorem. Quisque ut erat. Curabitur gravida nisi at nibh.","is_sender_user":true}]
```

It would be better to create a User table and create a JSONB messages field to store your messages. Or the way it is I can create my report using JSONB queries?

Comment: Considering all your fields are on top level you can create a GIN type index on the whole column - that should speed things a bit. Postgre also allows you to create indexes over a field in the jsonb (field_name -> 'created_at' for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Samuil Petrov mentioned you can create index on jsonb field, i suggest creating index on month part of `created_at` and `user`

```
create INDEX td002_si3 ON testData002 (substring(doc->>'created',0,8),(doc->>'user'));
```

with this the query

```
SELECT 
      substring(doc ->> 'created', 0, 8) AS m,
      ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT doc ->> 'user')          AS users
    FROM testData002
    GROUP BY substring(doc ->> 'created', 0, 8)
```

will give you the monthly users from an index scan

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=0.28..381.52 rows=3485 width=50)
  Group Key: ""substring""((doc ->> 'created'::text), 0, 8)
  ->  Index Scan using td002_si3 on testdata002  (cost=0.28..294.28 rows=3500 width=50)
```

test data generated with

```
create table testData002 as 
     select row_number() OVER () as id
           ,jsonb_build_object('created',dt::DATE
                              ,'user',(random()*1000)::INT) as doc 
       from generate_series(1,10),generate_series('2016-01-01'::TIMESTAMP,'2016-12-15'::TIMESTAMP,'1 day'::INTERVAL) as dt;
```

Comment: "GroupAggregate" is a Postgresql function? I'm running on pgadmin 3 and it does not recognize.

Comment: @cske Thanks for your response. The structure of my JSON is a bit different. I have the following in my table: The doc field receives an array [{"user": 1, "created": "2016-01-01"}, { "user": 14, "created": "2016-02- 04 "}, ...]

Comment: @JoãoPedro that can be easily transformed to structure used in answer

Answer (score 4):

Your message documents describe a relationship between users: a *sender* transmits content to a *recipient*. A sender may send many messages, a recipient may receive many messages. This is best represented in a relational structure, with a users table and a messages table having foreign key constraints for the sender and recipient.

It's possible to just heave everything into a JSONB field like you're doing, but there are some major disadvantages: query performance suffers, although as Samuil Petrov mentioned this can be ameliorated with indexing; but more importantly, there's nothing preventing a message from having an invalid user or recipient id. Using a schemaless JSONB field can simplify development while you're still hashing out what you need to store, but once you know what you need, it should be enforced by your schema.